# composing tasks with null checks within a method

Tags: java

I have the following method which checks different methods and returns a task depending on that method (`checkTask1()`-`checkTask7()`):

**version 1:**

```
public Task getTask() {
        Task t = null;
        t = checkTask1();
        if (t == null) t = checkTask2();
        if (t == null) t = checkTask3();
        if (t == null) t = checkTask4();
        if (t == null) t = checkTask5();
        if (t == null) t = checkTask6();
        if (t == null) t = checkTask7();

        return t != null ? t : new Task();
    }
```

Each `checkTask#`-method simply returns a dependent task or null if this task should not be created, for example `checkTask1()`:

```
private Task checkTask1() {
    // task1Enabled is a predefined boolean property
    if (task1Enabled) {
        // returns a task in relation to task1
        // involving different properties of task set
        var time = getTask1Time();
        return new Task(1, "myTask1", time);
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is a better code structure or method to achieve the above. Maybe with **Java Functional Interfaces (Producer, Consumer)** or simpler? The repeating null checks are a little ugly..

Comment: Could you show us what `checkTask%n%()` do?

Comment: @ruohola I updated the question with `checkTask%n%()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about creating a method like this :

```
Task get(Supplier<Task>... suppliers) {
    for(Supplier<Task> supplier : suppliers) {
        Task task = supplier.get();
        if(task != null) {
            return task;
        }
    }
    return new Task();
}
```

and then invoke it like :

```
Task task = get(this::checkTask1, this::checkTask2, this::checkTask3); //pass as many tasks as you want. Note that order is important.
```

Since it makes use of varargs array you can pass as many `Supplier`s as you want however I agree that having a method per task seems like an antipattern. It would be advisable to reconsider this design.

Regarding the first solution it might raise `Possible heap pollution` warning because of the generic varargs. To overcome this you could use a `List` instead of varargs :

```
Task get(List<Supplier<Task>> suppliers) {
//...
}

Task get = get(List.of(this::checkTask1, this::checkTask2));
```

Comment: Nice solution. However, I have a **3 questions..**

Comment: **1. question:** I get the warning `Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter suppliers` from the method body of `Task get(Supplier<Task>... suppliers)`. Can I safely ignore it?

Comment: **3. question:** You say: `a method per task seems like an antipattern`. Could you give a solution by refactoring my example which avoids this antipattern?

Comment: According to **3.question**: I can of course use only one method and doing a lot of `if..else`..however I had that before and my method was long. So I splitted this into smaller methods and now I want to compose the result..your approach seems good..but..the compiler warnings are not so nice..

Comment: What about `null`-values within `List.of()`? `List.of()` does not allow `null`-values..

Comment: 1. check my edited answer what to do to get rid of the warning. 2. I do not know what `OrderAdvice` is. From the code from MCVE it should not raise it. 3. What about creating an interface and several implementations - one per task? Then your code would be easier to extend - of course it depends on how much your tasks are smiliar/different. 4. This is a list of suppliers so I am not sure what you mean about `null` values there.

Comment: OrderAdvice was copy pase error..replace it by "Task".

Comment: The solution with Supplier works. Thanks! But you are right, creating an interface and several implementations would maybe better..However, your solution is nice.

Answer (score 2):

Having `N` amount of methods with the names `foo1`,`foo2`...`fooN` is almost always an antipattern and a design smell. In your case, this can be fixed quite easily.

Refactor your `checkTask` methods into one:

```
private Task checkTask(int i) {
    if (taskEnabled[i - 1]) {
        return new Task(i, "myTask" + i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Change the `taskEnabled` into an array of `boolean`s:

```
private boolean[] taskEnabled;
```

And finally refactor your `getTask` method:

```
public Task getTask() {
    Task t = null;
    int i = 1;
    while (t == null && i <= taskEnabled.length) {
        t = checkTask(i);
        i++;
    }
    return t != null ? t : new Task();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, was my fault. It cannot be refactored like yours above because ` return new Task(1, "myTask1");` was **only** an example. The construction for each task is very special and does not only involve the text 'myTask1`, but more properties related to this actual task. I made it clear in my question..

Comment: `Having N amount of methods with the names foo1,foo2...fooN is almost always an antipattern`. Yes you are right..such things should be refactored to an interface of `foo` with implementing classes foo1,foo2..fooN.